# Validating attribute names using a decorator

Tags: python, properties, decorator, python-decorators

I have a decorator class `validatekeys()` and a `Node3D()` class.

The intention is for `Node3D` to hold coordinate values of x, y, and z which are retrieved using a `@property` decorator, and can be set using either a `@coords.setter` decorator (which calls `set_coords()`) or directly using `set_coords()` which is itself decorated with `validatekeys()`. I am using decorators to accomplish this so that I can add other classes later, like `Node2D()`, for example.

Code:

```
class validatekeys(object):
    def __init__(self,*keysIterable):
        self.validkeys = []
        for k in keysIterable:
            self.validkeys.append(k)
    def __call__(self,f):
        def wrapped_f(*args,**kwargs):
            for a in kwargs:
                if not a in self.validkeys:
                    raise Exception()
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
            return f(self,**kwargs)
        return wrapped_f

class Node3D(object):
    @property
    def coords(self):
        return self.__dict__
    @coords.setter
    def coords(self,Coords):
        self.set_coords(**Coords)
    @validatekeys('x','y','z')
    def set_coords(self,**Coords):
        pass
```

However, part of the output is not as expected:

```
n = Node2D()
n.coords               #{} <--expected
n.set_coords(x=1,y=2)
n.coords               #{} <--not expected
n.set_coords(a=1,b=2)  #Exception  <--expected
```

It looks like the `self.__dict__` is not being updated correctly. However, I've been unable to figure out how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Note that although I am certainly interested in alternative formulations/approaches on solving this problem (validating keys input to a setter), this is mostly a learning exercise to understand how decorators, classes, etc etc work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator is updating the wrong `__dict__`; `self` in your decorator `__call__` is the *decorator object itself*.

You need to extract the bound `self` argument from the called wrapper:

```
def wrapped_f(*args, **kwargs):
    for a in kwargs:
        if not a in self.validkeys:
            raise Exception()
    instance = args[0]
    instance.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can give your `wrapped_f()` an explicit first argument too:

```
def wrapped_f(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    for a in kwargs:
        if not a in self.validkeys:
            raise Exception()
    instance.__dict__.update(kwargs)
    return f(instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here `instance` is bound to the `Node3D` instance. Note that there is no hard requirement to name this variable `self`; that is just a convention.

Comment: If you give `wrapped_f` an explicit first argument, it needs to have a different name than the one from the validator, to avoid shadowing it.  It needs access to the validator self in order to retrieve the list of valid keys, which is stored on the validator and not the Node3D object.

Comment: @BrenBarn: darn, missed the `self.validkeys` there.

Comment: choosing this as the correct answer since it is absolutely, positively, crystal clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `self` in your `__call__` refers to the validator, not the Node3D object, so the validator is updating its own `__dict__`.  Try this instead:

```
class validatekeys(object):
    def __init__(self,*keysIterable):
        self.validkeys = []
        for k in keysIterable:
            self.validkeys.append(k)
    def __call__(validator_self,f):
        def wrapped_f(self, *args,**kwargs):
            for a in kwargs:
                if not a in validator_self.validkeys:
                    raise Exception()
            self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_f
```

Here I've renamed the `self` in the `__call__` to `validator_self` to make it clear that that self refers to the validator.  I added a `self` to the wrapper function; this `self` will refer to the "real" self of the Node3D object where the validated method is.